# assign a number to every n consecutive dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'date': ['2019-12-22', '2019-12-22','2019-12-15','2019-12-15', 
                             '2019-12-08', '2019-12-08','2019-12-01', '2019-12-01',
                            '2019-11-24', '2019-11-24','2019-11-17', '2019-11-17',
                             '2019-11-10', '2019-11-10'],
                    'name':  ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']})
```

What I want to do is to assign a tag (number) to every two consecutive dates, from the most recent dates. Need result like below:

```
    date    name    tag
0   2019-12-22  A   1
1   2019-12-22  B   1
2   2019-12-15  A   1
3   2019-12-15  B   1
4   2019-12-08  A   2
5   2019-12-08  B   2
6   2019-12-01  A   2
7   2019-12-01  B   2
8   2019-11-24  A   3
9   2019-11-24  B   3
10  2019-11-17  A   3
11  2019-11-17  B   3
12  2019-11-10  A   4
13  2019-11-10  B   4
```

what is the best way to achieve that? need general solution that can apply to n consecutive dates.

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong "every two consecutive dates" is what he said.

Comment: here 'consecutive' is based on the available dates in the dateframe

Comment: @HenryYik true, sorry I misread it

Answer (score 1):

Using `cumsum` and floor division:

```
df["tag"] = (df["date"].eq(df["date"].shift(-1)).cumsum()+1)//2

print (df)

          date name  tag
0   2019-12-22    A    1
1   2019-12-22    B    1
2   2019-12-15    A    1
3   2019-12-15    B    1
4   2019-12-08    A    2
5   2019-12-08    B    2
6   2019-12-01    A    2
7   2019-12-01    B    2
8   2019-11-24    A    3
9   2019-11-24    B    3
10  2019-11-17    A    3
11  2019-11-17    B    3
12  2019-11-10    A    4
13  2019-11-10    B    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare difference for not equal by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and add [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['tag'] = df['date'].diff().dt.days.ne(0).cumsum()
print (df)
         date name  tag
0  2019-12-22    A    1
1  2019-12-22    B    1
2  2019-12-15    A    2
3  2019-12-15    B    2
4  2019-12-08    A    3
5  2019-12-08    B    3
6  2019-12-01    A    4
7  2019-12-01    B    4
8  2019-11-24    A    5
9  2019-11-24    B    5
10 2019-11-17    A    6
11 2019-11-17    B    6
12 2019-11-10    A    7
13 2019-11-10    B    7
```

If consecutive groups are not duplicated, it means like in sample data `2019-12-08` is replaced by `2019-12-22` use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) with integer division:

```
df['tag'] = pd.factorize(df['date'])[0] + 2 // 2
print (df)

          date name  tag
0   2019-12-22    A    1
1   2019-12-22    B    1
2   2019-12-15    A    2
3   2019-12-15    B    2
4   2019-12-08    A    3
5   2019-12-08    B    3
6   2019-12-01    A    4
7   2019-12-01    B    4
8   2019-11-24    A    5
9   2019-11-24    B    5
10  2019-11-17    A    6
11  2019-11-17    B    6
12  2019-11-10    A    7
13  2019-11-10    B    7
```